# Generation of all sequences of length N from numbers 0.1…k-1 with minimal changes

Tags: c++, algorithm

For example, I have a code that generates all sequences of zeros and ones of length 4. Can I do it using his example?

```
#define n 2

int x[n];

int main() {
    int i, k;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x[i] = 0;
    }
        
    while (1) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout << x[i];
        }

        cout << endl << endl;

        for (k = n - 1; k >= 0 && x[k] == 1; k--) {
            x[k] = 0;
        }

        if (k == -1) {
            break;
        } else {
            x[k] = 1;
        }                     
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example:
[image]

Comment: Might std::next_permutation (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) be what you are looking for?

Comment: Basically the same algorithm will work, but you need to cycle through more than two options at every digit position. It's just counting, which I'm sure you know how to do.. Why don't you give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

Basically your task is to output all `N`-digit numbers in base `K` in ascending order.

I encoded two solutions for your task. First solution looks very similar to your code. It is non-recursive, but algorithmical.

Base of this solution is following algorithm - we go from tail of a number while all digits are equal to `K - 1` (for example equal to `9` in case of famous base `10`) and zeroize them, and first digit smaller than `K - 1` we increment. This way we generate next number using previous number. This is also how usually people increment any long number by 1 in their minds.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/18GWMzavM)

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void Gen(size_t n, size_t k, auto const & outf) {
    std::vector<size_t> a(n);
    while (true) {
        outf(a);
        int i = 0;
        for (i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (a[i] < k - 1)
                break;
            a[i] = 0;
        }
        if (i < 0)
            break;
        ++a[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    Gen(2, 3, [](auto const & v){
        for (auto e: v)
            std::cout << e << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    });
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 
0 1 
0 2 
1 0 
1 1 
1 2 
2 0 
2 1 
2 2
```

---

Second solution uses approach of [Recursive Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_function).

For those who knows recursive functions this second solution looks simpler and doesn't need invention of any algorithms like in first solution.

Basically in a loop I increment most significant digit (left-most) and recursively with same loop I iterate through all possible numbers in a tail. When tail goes through all possible numbers only then most significant digit is incremented again.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/hK15cM6Wa)

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void Gen(size_t n, size_t k, auto const & outf) {
    std::vector<size_t> a(n);
    std::function<void(size_t pos)> Rec = [&](auto pos){
        if (pos >= n) {
            outf(a);
            return;
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
            a[pos] = i;
            Rec(pos + 1);
        }
    };
    Rec(0);
}

int main() {
    Gen(2, 3, [](auto const & v){
        for (auto e: v)
            std::cout << e << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    });
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 
0 1 
0 2 
1 0 
1 1 
1 2 
2 0 
2 1 
2 2
```

---

If the task is to improve your code with minimal changes, to achieve final goal, then it will be following snippet (see `n` and `K` defined at start of program).

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/63KbczKn8)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define n 2
#define K 3

int x[n];

int main() {
    int i, k;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x[i] = 0;
    }
        
    while (1) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout << x[i] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;

        for (k = n - 1; k >= 0 && x[k] == K - 1; k--) {
            x[k] = 0;
        }

        if (k == -1) {
            break;
        } else {
            ++x[k];
        }                     
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 
0 1 
0 2 
1 0 
1 1 
1 2 
2 0 
2 1 
2 2
```